# Facebook Wall post stream attachments

Tags: facebook, post, stream

Have you seen those Facebook wall posts from Foursquare? It shows a map of the area from where the user has checked in. On top of that, there is an overlay with the title of the checkin, a description and three photos of the location, each containing a link to Foursquare. How do they do this?

I know how to post a picture to a user's wall using the Javascript SDK, but how do you create these more interactive fragments? I've looked at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/ but can't find much more information on this. Are these attachments what Foursquare is using?

Comment: It's like a "map" object on the open graph. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-aggregation/#layout